# Relation between quotients and subalgebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-algebra

If I have two algebras $A,B$, and one is the quotient of the other, i.e. there exists a surjective morphism $\phi : A  \to B$. Then is $B$ isomorphic to some subalgebra of $A$? I think so, because I just need to select for each equivalence class $\phi^{-1}(b)$ one element $a \in \phi^{-1}(b)$, and furthermore if I had selected $a_1 \in \phi^{-1}(b_1), a_2 \in \phi^{-1}(b_2)$, and $a_3 \in \phi^{-1}(b_1 \cdot b_2)$, then $a_3 = a_1 \cdot a_2$ must hold. Which could be realized I think.

On the other hand, if I have a subalgebra $A'$ of $A$, could it always be realisied as a quotient, i.e. is there some surjective $\psi : A \to A'$. I think this should be possible. But then if quotients and subalgebras are so related, then they are in some sense the same concepts, but as I see it they are threated quite differently in textbooks and theorems, so they are not the same, which make me doubt my constructions. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: No. You are looking for a section of $\phi$ which might not be a homomorphism. This would only happen if $B$ is a summand of $A$.

Comment: For an example of why it fails, consider $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: ah ok Tobias, your example is quite clear, thank you. and for the other direction, is every subalgebra homomorphic image? @Prahlad Vaidyanathan: I don't understand your comment...

Comment: For the other direction, take any field. It has no non-trivial quotients, but it may well have non-trivial subrings.

Comment: ok makes sense, but I meant subalgebras over the same signature! so in your example just subrings are not valid, because for them the operation "$^{-1}$" is not defined.

Comment: What do you mean by same signature? What definition of algebra are you using?

Comment: Signature in the sense of universal algebra, for example a group is an algbra over $(G, \cdot, ^{-1}, 1)$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra

Comment: Ahh, I am not really familiar with universal algebra. I assumed that an algebra (in the sense of an algebra over a ring) was also an algebra in the sense of universal algebra.

Comment: @Stefan Fields are also rings, so this example works fine in the category of rings.  But in the category of fields, there are still examples, since a field never has nontrivial quotients, but can still have nontrivial sub-_fields_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO of course. Take for example any algebra $A$ with has no 1-element subalgera and take their 1-element quotient $B$.